# sticky modal changes it's location on zoom in/out, and browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my modal. I'm already done making it slide down when a button is clicked using jquery. Now my problem is whenever i zoom in, zoom out, or resize my browser the location of the modal changes. I want the modal to stick to the position that I want. Here's my code:

```
    <script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#login").click(function(){
$("#form").slideDown(400);
 });
  $("#close").click(function(){
$("#form").slideUp(400);
 });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#form
{
display:none;
position:absolute !important;
top:300px !important;
left:820px !important;
margin-top:-120px !important;
margin-left:-500px !important;
z-index:101;
}
</style>
```

As you can see on my codes above, I fixed the position of my modal in CSS using top and left. But when I zoom out/in, or resize the browser the location changes. How can I make it stick in a fixed position? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I fixed it myself. I just have to remove some codes in css. Here's the new CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#form
{
display:none;
position:absolute !important;
z-index:101;
}
</style>
```

Hope this helps to everybody who have the same problem.

Comment: you took out the positioning so it's always on the top left. you could as well add `top: 0` and `left: 0`

Answer (score 0):

use `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`

Comment: where do you want the modal to stick? top right? then use the css properties `top` and `right` instead of `top` and `left`. Using `position: fixed` is the right way to go though

Comment: i want the modal to stick on the left side. the problem of fixed is that whenever i scroll down the modal stays, i just want the modal to really stick on a specified location. Scrolling and zooming won't change that location, that's what i want to happen.. :-(

Comment: i set up a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9pSyN/ for me it looks like the modal is staying in the same position. when you scroll of course it might scroll out of the window but it still stays at the same position relative to the document